# How to write a method that can handle Task and ValueTask?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Imagine you want to write a method similar to the following one. It wraps a function returning a `ValueTask<T>` with trivial performance monitoring code:

```
static async Task Measure<T>(Func<ValueTask<T>> body)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting perf test");
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await body();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to write this function once so that it can receive `Func<ValueTask<T>>` **and** `Func<Task<T>>`?

Of course you could simply duplicate the code and change just the parameter's type.

```
static async Task Measure<T>(Func<Task<T>> body) { ... }
```

The implementation would be absolutely identical. I am asking myself if it is possible to avoid this kind of code duplication when having to deal with `ValueTask` and `Task`. Up to now, I could not come up with a good solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

According to official documentation: [Generalized async return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types)

> The `ValueTask` struct has a constructor with a `Task` parameter so that you can construct a `ValueTask` from the return value of any existing async method:

That means you can write an overload that will wrap the `body` and call only one method that will do the work

```
static Task Measure<T>(Func<Task<T>> body)
{
    var wrapped = () => new ValueTask<T>( body() );
    return Measure( wrapped );
}

static async Task Measure<T>(Func<ValueTask<T>> body)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting perf test");
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await body();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I am aware of this ValueTask constructor. However, this adds some overhead that I want to avoid. It has to allocate a Task on top of ValueTask. This eliminates the advantage of ValueTask.

It is not possible to generalize the function so that you don't need to do that wrapping, right?

Again, thank you for pointing out that solution. For many situations it is a good way to go.

Comment: @Rainer ValueTask is expected to be used in rare cases, so a method expecting `Task` would be a more generic way to do this. `ValueTask`  If you rephrase the question to "How can my method handle generalized async return types?" the problem becomes far more interesting (and potentially annoying).